# need help in using friend functions in c++

Tags: c++, class, oop, friend, friend-function

I'm a newbie to C++.I wrote a simple program to implement the use of friend functions. The code is as follows:-

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class one
{
   private:
       int age;
   public:
       one()
       {
           age=1;
       }

       void setData(int num)
       {
           age=num;
       }

   friend int returnOne()
   {
       return age;
   }
};

class two
{
   private:
       int roll;
   public:
       two()
       {
          roll=0;
       }

       void setData(int num)
       {
          roll=num;
       }

   friend int returnTwo()
   {
       return roll;
   }
};

int main()
{
    one a;
    two b;
    cout<<a.returnOne()<<endl<<b.returnTwo()<<endl;
}
```

I'm getting the following error in c++.

```
friend.cpp: In function ‘int returnOne()’:
friend.cpp:8:6: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘one::age’
friend.cpp:20:9: error: from this location
friend.cpp: In function ‘int returnTwo()’:
friend.cpp:27:6: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘two::roll’
friend.cpp:39:9: error: from this location
friend.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
friend.cpp:47:10: error: ‘class one’ has no member named ‘returnOne’
friend.cpp:47:31: error: ‘class two’ has no member named ‘returnTwo’
```

**EDIT**
Thanks.It solved the problem.

But it now leads me to another question.Isn't  the friend keyword now compromised the purpose of using `private`,as now any class or function can simply use the friend function to access private data members.If yes,them we could have simply declared the data member as `public` instead of `private`.Whats so special in using `private`?

Comment: This question title immediately made me think of a particular song by Joe Cocker. :-}

Comment: @FrerichRaabe you mean by The Beatles?

Comment: @juanchopanza: You're right! I just always think of the version by Joe Cocker. Now that you mention it, I remember that the song was specifically written for Ringo because he could single only a few (five?) different tones. Anyway, I'm getting distracted...

Comment: @insane See http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2x4fzdz.aspx) link

> A friend function is a function that is not a member of a class but
>   has access to the class's private and protected members. Friend
>   functions are not considered class members; they are normal external
>   functions that are given special access privileges. Friends are not in
>   the class's scope, and they are not called using the member-selection
>   operators (. and –>) unless they are members of another class. A
>   friend function is declared by the class that is granting access. The
>   friend declaration can be placed anywhere in the class declaration. It
>   is not affected by the access control keywords.

Comment: :Thanks it solved the problem.But it now leads me to another question.Isn't  the friend keyword now compromised the purpose of using `private`.If yes,them we could have simply declared the data member as `public` instead of `private`.Whats so special in using `private`?

Comment: @InsaneCoder `private` basically means nobody can access it except for the class itself and its friends. `public` would give access to everyone.

Comment: @InsaneCoder yes and no: no - because the class is responsible to say if there is a friend function  and doesn't have to give a friend function. yes - if the class gave a friend function that everyone can use and told the world what the friend class is and what private member she has then the class is compromised

Comment: It' worth mentioning that when you have to use friend function/classes it usually means that there's something wrong with design of your application. So learn about them, but try to use them as little as possible. ;)